# Showing $P^n $ is isomorphic to $R^{n+1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Show $P^n$, the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\le n$ with real coefficients, is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

I always have trouble showing that a function is one to one and onto. So i feel that this is going to be the trouble spot of my proof.

Pf:

Let $L: P^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1};\\ L(a_nt^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....a_0) = [a_n, a_{n-1},....a_0]$

Now in order to show that these two spaces are isopmorphic i have to show that this function is one-to-one, onto, and satisfies the two linearity properties of a transformation.

One to one:

Assume $$L(a_nt^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....a_0) = L(b_nt^n + b_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....b_0) $$
$$\implies[a_n, a_{n-1},....a_0] = [b_n, b_{n-1},....b_0] \in \mathbb R^{n+1} $$
$$\implies a_n = b_n,....a_0 = b_0$$
$$\implies a_nt^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....a_0 = b_nt^n + b_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....b_0$$
Therefore it is one to one.

Onto:

Let $[s_n, s_{n-1},...s_0] \in \mathbb R^{n+1} $. This means i need to find $a_nt^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....a_0$ such that $L(a_nt^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+.....a_0) =[s_n, s_{n-1},...s_0]$

Well based on how i defind my function i could just let $[a_n, a_{n-1},....a_0] = [s_n, s_{n-1},...s_0]$

And that should prove the function is onto.

The other two conditions i am fine with, it is just these ones that trip me up everytime regardless of it being ina general scenario or a specific function.

Comment: The proofs of one-to-one and onto both look fine. However, I still think there is a gap in your proof of isomorphism. Namely, you have not proved that $L$ is well-defined. Assuming that you have equality of the two polynomials $a_n t^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1} + … + a_0 = b_n t^n + b_{n-1} t^{n-1} + … + b_0$, how do you prove that they have the same coefficient sequences $[a_n,a_{n-1},…,a_0] = [b_n,b_{n-1},..,b_0]$?

Comment: Thinking about it, I can honestly say I am  ot sure....

Comment: "Fopr whatever reason or another the bane of my existance always falls down to showing that a function is one to one and onto. " That sentence is a mess. You get more and better answers by keeping it simple and get to your question as fast as possible. Even if you cleaned up that first sentence, starting "For one reason or another, the bane of my existence always..." it would be difficult to comprehend by the many non-native English speakers around here who might want to help you. What is "Pf?" You go all flowery at the start, and can't even spell out a word when you get to the question?

Comment: Then: "Now in order to show that these two spaces..." You haven't mentioned two spaces. You'd defined an $L$ without telling us what space $L$ is a function of.

Comment: I get what your saying @ThomasAndrews, I just personally feel that if I don't give some feeling about it, I would come off as demanding. You guys already grasciously donate your own oersonal time to the gorwth of this site that I don't want to sound like "i have question, give me answer" in a demanding air

Comment: But making the language hard to read and not getting to the point is *not* respectful of the time people are spending helping you. Stating that these problems are a bane to your existence is about you, not about respecting the answerers, and has nothing to do with the question. In fact, you never state the problem you are trying to solve (implicitly, it is in the title, but one has to deduce what $P^n$ is.)

Comment: Fair enough. I will take your reccomendation and apply it from here on.